# Found two old questions which are duplicates

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

While searching for something today, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9259451/size-of-class-c/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6875783/size-of-classes-with-virtual-functions-gcc-xcode) which are close enough that I would consider them to be duplicates. Both are at least 2 years old.

Should I close one as duplicate of the other (probably - close the second one as the first one has better answers), or let sleeping dogs lie?

Comment: If they really are dup, just close them as dup. Choose the better one as target.